# Bash while loop script that runs Nmap with iterating IP and port number

Tags: bash, while-loop, increment, nmap

Summary: I'm trying to create a Bash script that selects an IP address and it's associated open ports, then run each IP through Nmap and display/store the results.

The format of the ports file (portsList):

```
192.168.1.1   53   udp
192.168.1.1   80   tcp
192.168.1.1   1900 tcp
192.168.1.110 135  tcp
192.168.1.115 1080 tcp
```

The format of the IP file (ipList):

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.110
192.168.1.115
```

My Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
portsvar="$(cat formattedPorts)"
hostvar="$(cat oneHost)"

while read -r line;
do
echo "$line" > oneHost
grep -wf oneHost portsList | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ',' > formattedPorts
nmap -n -sV -p"$portsvar" "$hostvar" >> scanResults
cat scanResults
done < ipList
```

I spent several hours, trying multiple variations of this code and tried to find a solution online. But to no avail. The most this script can do is scan and output for the first selected IP and ports.

Additional considerations would be; if a port is UDP, to append 'U:' on the ports option. Also, if there is a way to display the output of Nmap scanning, while it is being redirected '>>' to a file.

Bash is what I'm most familiar with, but I'm open to learning a solution in a different language.

*Edit*
I tried jhnc's solution below by replacing:

```
echo "$line" > oneHost
grep -wf oneHost portsList | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ',' > formattedPorts
nmap -n -sV -p"$portsvar" "$hostvar" >> scanResults
cat scanResults
```

with jhnc's code in the comment below. the resulting output was:

```
nmap -n -sV -p T:135 192.168.1.110
nmap -n -sV -p T:5985 192.168.1.112
nmap -n -sV -p T:54112,T:60000,T:8009,T:8888 192.168.1.131
nmap -n -sV -p T:5040 192.168.1.132
nmap -n -sV -p T:1041,T:1900,T:20005,T:33344,T:49152,T:49153,T:80 192.168.1.1
```

This output was echo'ed onto the terminal 5 times. From this I'll try to find a solution to have the input of this group of IP's ran once.

Comment: Why do you need the `oneHost` file? Why not just `grep -w "$line" portsList`?

Comment: You can also do it in awk: `awk -v ip="$line" '$1 == line { print $2 }`

Comment: please update the question with the contents of the `formattedPorts` and `oneHost` files; also update the question with **a)** the (wrong) output generated by your script and **b)** the (correct) desired output (making sure it matches with the sample input data you've provided)

Comment: as for the *"if there is a way to display the output of Nmap scanning, while it is being redirected '>>' to a file"* ... take a look at the `tee` command (or `tee -a` if the intention is to append to the output file)

Comment: `awk 'NR==FNR{q[$1]++;next} q[$1]{p[$1]=p[$1](p[$1]?",":"")($3=="udp"?"U:":"T:")$2}END{for(i in p)system(sprintf("echo nmap -n -sV -p %s %s\n",p[i],i))}' ipList portsList | tee -a scanResults`

Comment: Thank you for the responses. The formattedPorts and oneHost files are empty files, until the script inputs the values into them.

Comment: @jhnc Thank you, I will try this.

Comment: `echo'ed onto the terminal 5 times, and did not execute Nmap.` What do you think the `echo` in `sprintf("echo nmap -n..` is for? What do you think will happen if you remove the `echo`?

Comment: Just caught that (updated my post), now it is executing. I'm still trying to have the input executed once